# Facebook SDK on Android : override or hide the progress dialog when I log in

Tags: android, facebook, authentication, progressdialog

I'm using the Facebook SDK 3.0 for Android with the uiHelper and the loginButton. When I press the login button a progress dialog is displayed. Is it possible to custom it or replace it with another dialog ? How ?
I'm pretty sure that's possible, Candy crush do it ...
Moreover, I try to log user without the uiHelper but with the traditionnal method :
 session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(this).setCallback(statusCallback));
I've the same issue, I don't understand how this progress dialog is displayed.

Thank you all !

Comment: The FB SDK sources are available on github. You can change there whatever you want

Comment: Do you know the class which is concerned by the progress dialog ?

Comment: The class com.facebook.LoginActivity has an authorizationClient field and the method setBackgroundProcessingListener with 2 callbacks(line 75 SDK 3.0) display this spinner. Unfortunately, there isn't callback for your activity.

Answer (score 0):

you can go directly to the Facebook Library project added to your Project ,
Go inside the code and change it .

this is an example from WebDialog Class , i simply removed the show method of
the ProgressDialog:

```
    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        Utility.logd(LOG_TAG, "Webview loading URL: " + url);
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        if (!isDetached) {
            //spinner.show();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For facebook-android-sdk-4.4.1

It can be changed in com/facebook/login/loginFragment
look for  com_facebook_login_activity_progress_bar and set the visibility to GONE like this

```
R.id.com_facebook_login_activity_progress_bar).setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: How can i edit loginfragment? I have opened it in android studio but it wont let me edit

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28952681/1435712) to hide the Facebook process dialog, and then implement your own when the Facebook login is pressed.