# While ParseLoginUI loading spinner is working activity is visible at background

Tags: android, facebook, parse-platform

For my project, I am using ParseLoginUI with a dispatcher as shown here: https://github.com/ParsePlatform/ParseUI-Android/tree/master/ParseLoginSampleWithDispatchActivity

However, when I click "Login with Facebook", Parse spinner starts spinning, also my activity which I should go "after" this step is also getting visible (it looks really ugly) and then it directs me to facebook login widget and to the activity.

It should look like this:
[image]

Yet, I also see this step:

[image]

Which is pretty disgusting. How can I stick with only first animation? I guess Activity is starting prematurely.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the solution. That dummy activity which starts unnecessarily is belong to Facebook. Which in our `AndroidManifest.xml` Facebook's LoginActivity looks like this:

```
<activity android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity">
```

Add NoDisplay as Theme to it, so it doesn't show up on screen:

```
<activity android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"
          android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay">
```

Comment: This causes a crash in Android 6 (M)

Comment: It does crashes on SDK 23+ but it's not a bug, read more here (https://commonsware.com/blog/2015/11/02/psa-android-6p0-theme.nodisplay-regression.html)

Answer (score 1):

With update of new facebook sdk it is now works like this

```
<activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay"
        tools:replace="android:theme"
        />
```